# Post a form to standalone aspx page from MVC5 controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to submit a form from MVC controller to ASPX page
There are many examples from where you can submit a form from view to controller action but I am unable to find a solution for subject method.

Here is ASPX code

```
Value1= string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form.Get("Value1")) ? string.Empty : Request.Form.Get("Value1").Trim();

Value2= string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form.Get("Value2")) ? string.Empty : Request.Form.Get("Value2").Trim();

Value3= string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form.Get("Value3")) ? string.Empty : Request.Form.Get("Value3").Trim();
```

And I have to call aspx page from a controller action using url

Comment: So you want to call MVC method from another MVC method?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale no on page load on aspx page I get values from a submitted form, previously it was done by jquery from view, but now I have to pass values as submitted form from MVC contoller action

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a WebAPI Controller rather than a standard MVC Controller. 
Do try this example: [Using Web API with ASP.NET Web Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms). You may use AJAX as in here or calling the WebAPI from the Code Behind of the ASP.Net page. Or you may rather bypass using controllers and use the code behind instead? It depends on your requirement.

Comment: A demo or helping URL will do great...!